# Mobile Test Workbench - Native keyboard issue

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mtww

I'm using Worklight 6.2, dojo 1.8 and mtww 8.6.

I have built a small sample which consists of a screen with a text box, I input some text into it, and the input apears on a div somewhere on my screen.

My issue is with native keyboards, it seems that MTWW doesn't notice that the div has a input field and doesn't pop up the keyboard to input something into it.
So, when I play back my recording, it simply doesn't input anything and the test is unsuccessful.

My question is if this is the expected behavior, and it's me that will need to tune manually the recording script to manually set the field I wanted to affect.

Comment: - when you record, do you see a "enter text" instruction in the script ?
- if you click on the input, does the keyboard appear ?
- Can you verify the behavior with the original app ?
- what is your device ?
- Do you have this behavior on Android or iOS or both ?

Comment: Hi, no. It appears as a "click on something that has content like <text i've written on native keyboard>". When I click the textbox the keyboard appear. This is working fine on the original app. I'm working with a iphone 4s and I'm not using a android devide.

Answer (score 0):

Re-Hi Silva,

In order to be sure, just the same question as in your other question... is your device (iPhone 6) under an iOS 8 release - which is not yet supported by MTWW 8.6?

Alexandre.

Comment: Hi, this issue is not related with iphone 6, I has testing it with iphone 4S which is still using iOS 7.0.4